# merge two schema tables including dependent tables also in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 3 tables in schema abc.They are

user_data

user_addr

user sal

Same 3 tables available in other schema xyz also.We need to merge xyz schema tables into abc schema tables.but condition is:

1) if userid not exist then insert.
2) if userid already exist and its email id differ then insert the record but update the user_id with seq.next_value in all 3 tables.

For example:

In Abc schema:

table user_date

```
user_id  name     email_id           date
1        gaurav    gav@gmail.com      21-01-2018
```

table user_add

```
user_id  addres       pin
1        GZB          325123
```

table use_sal

```
user_id   sal    effective date
1         25000   22-05-2018
```

In XYZschema:

table user_date

```
user_id  name     email_id           date
1        Arun arun@gmail.com      25-01-2018
5        kk    kk@gmail.com       26-06-2018
```

table user_add

```
user_id  addres       pin
1        Noida        789546
5        HYD          564231
```

table use_sal

```
user_id   sal    effective date
1         35000   22-06-2018
5         45000   25-07-2018
```

So ,I need final output in schema abc is.If next value of sequence is 100 then

table user_date

```
user_id  name     email_id           date
1        gaurav    gav@gmail.com      21-01-2018
5        kk       kk@gmail.com       26-06-2018
100      Arun     arun@gmail.com      25-01-2018
```

table user_add

```
user_id  addres       pin
1        GZB          325123
5        HYD          564231
100      Noida        789546
```

table use_sal

```
user_id   sal    effective date
1         25000   22-05-2018
5         45000   25-07-2018
100       35000   22-06-2018
```

I just given example of few records.I have 1000 of rows in the tables.Please suggest how to get this.  We can access xyz table in schema abc as xyz.user_data.

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: This is not a single question. These are multiple. I'd suggest you split this into multiple problems to solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try the following PL/SQL block**

```
DECLARE 
    l_user user_data.user_id%TYPE;
    l_email user_data.email_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT d.user_id,d.name,d.email_id,d.jdate,a.addr,a.pin,s.sal,s.eff_date 
            FROM xyz.user_data d
            INNER JOIN xyz.user_addr a
            ON d.user_id=a.user_id
            INNER JOIN xyz.user_sal s
            ON d.user_id=s.user_id)
  LOOP
     BEGIN
        SELECT user_id,email_id
          INTO l_user,l_email
          FROM abc.user_data
         WHERE user_id=i.user_id;
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        l_user := NULL;
        l_email := NULL;
     END;
     IF l_user IS NULL THEN
         INSERT INTO abc.user_data VALUES
         (i.user_id,i.name,i.email_id,i.jdate);

         INSERT INTO abc.user_addr VALUES
         (i.user_id,i.addr,i.pin);

         INSERT INTO abc.user_sal VALUES
         (i.user_id,i.sal,i.eff_date);

     ELSIF l_user IS NOT NULL AND l_email != i.email_id THEN

        SELECT abc.userid.NEXTVAL INTO l_user FROM DUAL;

         INSERT INTO abc.user_data VALUES
         (l_user,i.name,i.email_id,i.jdate);

         INSERT INTO abc.user_addr VALUES
         (l_user,i.addr,i.pin);

         INSERT INTO abc.user_sal VALUES
         (l_user,i.sal,i.eff_date);
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL-only approach**

Due to the restrictions on CURRVAL and NEXTVAL eg they cannot be used with DISTINCT, or in a subquery, or in a UNION etc (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11796)) it is a bit tricky to solve the problem using SQL.  Here's a solution which leaves the original tables intact (tested w/ Oracle 12c and 11g).  Steps:

{1} Create a table (called TEMP_) by JOINing all 3 tables of a "table set",  label each row in the resulting table T1 and T2, respectively.  UNION the result sets.

{2} Create the SEQUENCE.

{3} Create MASTER_ table, containing {a} rows for each unique ID (first query) and {b} rows whose ids occur more than once, with a NEWID column populated with values from the sequence (starting with 100000 in this example).

{4} Create 3 new details tables by SELECTing the appropriate columns from the MASTER_.

Tidy up: drop TEMP_ and MASTER_

-- {1}

```
-- table TEMP_ contains unaltered data from _both_ table sets ( 2 x 3 tables )
-- multiple ID columns removed
-- short names for the original tables: 
-- ud -> user_data, ua -> user_addr, us -> user_sal
--
create table temp_
as
select 'TS1' as table_set
, ud1.user_id, ud1.name, ud1.email_id, ud1.date_
, ua1.address, ua1.pin
, us1.sal, us1.effective_date
from ud1 
  join ua1 on ud1.user_id = ua1.user_id 
  join us1 on ud1.user_id = us1.user_id 
union
select 'TS2' as table_set
, ud2.user_id, ud2.name, ud2.email_id, ud2.date_
, ua2.address, ua2.pin
, us2.sal, us2.effective_date
from ud2 
  join ua2 on ud2.user_id = ua2.user_id 
  join us2 on ud2.user_id = us2.user_id 
;
```

-- {2}

```
create sequence uid_seq start with 100000 increment by 1 ;
```

-- {3a} find unique IDs (.NEXTVAL not needed)

```
-- column list should be coded (omitted here for clarity)
create table master_ as
select unique_ids.user_id as newid, unique_ids.*
from (
  select table_set
  , user_id, name, email_id, date_  -- table ud
  , address, pin                    -- table ua
  , sal, effective_date             -- table us
  , row_number() over ( partition by user_id order by table_set ) id_occurences
  from temp_ 
) unique_ids
where id_occurences = 1 ;
```

-- {3b} find duplicate IDs, replace them by sequence.NEXTVAL

```
-- We cannot use UNION on the 2 resultsets {3a} and {3b} when creating the MASTER_ table,
-- due to the fact that we are using .NEXTVAL (for duplicate user_ids).
-- However, this 2-step approach works. (CTAS, and subsequent INSERT ... SELECT)
-- 
-- column list should be coded (omitted here for clarity)
insert into master_
select uid_seq.nextval as newid, duplicates.*
from (
  select table_set
--  , uid_seq.nextval  -- throws ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
  , user_id, name, email_id, date_  -- table ud
  , address, pin                    -- table ua
  , sal, effective_date             -- table us
  , row_number() over ( partition by user_id order by table_set ) id_occurences
  from temp_ 
) duplicates
where id_occurences > 1 
;
```

-- {4} populate the new "part" tables with data from the MASTER_

```
-- ud: "user_data"
create table udnew 
as 
select newid, name, email_id, date_ from master_ ;

-- ua: "user_add"
create table uanew 
as 
select newid, address, pin from master_ ;

-- us: "use_sal"
create table usnew 
as 
select newid, sal, effective_date from master_ ;
```

The new tables contain ...

```
SQL> select * from udnew ;

     NEWID NAME   EMAIL_ID       DATE_    
---------- ------ -------------- ---------
         1 gaurav gav@gmail.com  21-JAN-18
         5 kk     kk@gmail.com   26-JUN-18
    100000 Arun   arun@gmail.com 25-JAN-18

SQL> select * from uanew ;

     NEWID ADDRE        PIN
---------- ----- ----------
         1 GZB       325123
         5 HYD       564231
    100000 Noida     789546

SQL> select * from usnew ;

     NEWID        SAL EFFECTIVE
---------- ---------- ---------
         1      25000 22-MAY-18
         5      45000 25-JUL-18
    100000      35000 22-JUN-18
```

Test data and more details: see [Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc137267e01119acf73c657de2f309e3)

**Alternative approach: use SQL and PL/SQL**

When using PL/SQL, we could maybe do the following: {1} create copies of the "second set" of tables, {2} create the required sequence, {3} write and execute a procedure that UPDATEs the copied table, using .NEXTVALs wherever needed.{4} Create 3 new tables by writing and executing UNIONs for each of the tables in "table set 1", combining them with the corresponding (copied) updated tables of "table set 2" as it were.

-- {1} create copies of the "second set" of tables

```
create table ud2copy as select * from ud2 ;
create table ua2copy as select * from ua2 ;
create table us2copy as select * from us2 ;
```

-- {2} create the required sequence

```
create sequence uid_seq start with 100000 increment by 1 ;
```

-- {3} procedure for UPDATING the copied tables with the required .NEXTVALS

```
create or replace procedure updateIDs
is
begin
  for rec_ in (
    select uid_seq.nextval new_id, ud2copy.user_id
    from ud1 
      join ud2copy on ud1.user_id = ud2copy.user_id 
    where ud1.email_id <> ud2copy.email_id
  )
  loop
    update ud2copy set user_id = rec_.new_id where user_id = rec_.user_id ;
    update ua2copy set user_id = rec_.new_id where user_id = rec_.user_id ;
    update us2copy set user_id = rec_.new_id where user_id = rec_.user_id ;
  end loop;
end ;
/

begin
  updateIDs ;
  commit ;
end ;
/
```

-- {4} create 3 new tables

```
create table udnew as select * from ud1 union select * from ud2copy ;
create table uanew as select * from ua1 union select * from ua2copy ;
create table usnew as select * from us1 union select * from us2copy ;
```

Result: the new tables contain ...

```
SQL> select * from udnew ;

   USER_ID NAME   EMAIL_ID       DATE_    
---------- ------ -------------- ---------
         1 gaurav gav@gmail.com  21-JAN-18
         5 kk     kk@gmail.com   26-JUN-18
    100000 Arun   arun@gmail.com 25-JAN-18

SQL> select * from uanew ;

   USER_ID ADDRE        PIN
---------- ----- ----------
         1 GZB       325123
         5 HYD       564231
    100000 Noida     789546

SQL> select * from usnew ;

   USER_ID        SAL EFFECTIVE
---------- ---------- ---------
         1      25000 22-MAY-18
         5      45000 25-JUL-18
    100000      35000 22-JUN-18
```

[Dbfiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d88874af358d0c589499aa538f5a2fc)

*Comment writers: no BULK or FORALL operations here ... we know: this procedure code is not as effective as it could be.  However, the PL/SQL code should be "fast enough", as we are only dealing with several thousand rows (per table).*